# How to fix 'A component is changing a controlled input of type text to be uncontrolled.' in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to make a calculator app with hooks instead of classes and it says that there isn't any controlled component going on.

I've tried removing the 'value' from the input but that results in nothing showing up.

```
function handleOperator() {
    console.log(isSubmitted)
    const f = [form.firstNum]
    const l = [form.lastNum]
    const Plus = f + l
    const Minus = f - l
    const Multiply = f * l
    const Divide = f / l
    switch (Operator) {
        case 'plus':
            return setSum(Plus), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'minus':
            return setSum(Minus), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'multiply':
            return setSum(Multiply), setSubmitted(false)
        case 'divide':
            return setSum(Divide), setSubmitted(false)
        default:
            return null
    }

}

function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type } = event.target
    if (type === 'text') {
        setForm({
            form,
            [name]: value
        })
    }
    console.log(form.firstNum)

}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    setSubmitted(true)
}


return (
    <div>
        <p>{isSubmitted === true && Sum}</p>
        <button name="Plus" onClick={() => { setOperator('plus'); handleOperator() }}>+</button>
        <button name="Minus" onClick={() => { setOperator('minus'); handleOperator() }}> -</button >
        <button name="Multiply" onClick={() => { setOperator('multiply'); handleOperator() }}>*</button>
        <button name="Divide" onClick={() => { setOperator('divide'); handleOperator() }}>/</button>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <input name="form.firstNum" type="text" value={form.firstNum} onChange={handleChange} />
            <input name="form.secondNum" type="text" value={form.secondNum} onChange={handleChange} />
            <br />
            <button> = </button>
        </form>

    </div >
)
```

I expected for when I type in the first and last numbers, I click the operation I want to be done and then the equal sign and it to show the answer. I also want to solve this bug while keeping most of my code intact.

Comment: @Jayce444 The input values are set to " " by default.

Comment: Ok, the solution was to put a ... in front of the "form" under setForm.